# Make a bigger space between menu items (nav)

Tags: html, css

I started creating my first web-page with HTML5 and some CSS styles in it. I have faced a problem i was hoping some could clear out for me.

I'm trying to make space between my menu items like:

```
ABOUT        HELP       CONTACT
```

I have found a simple method in how to do that, but it does not do the job good enough. As an example i have 2 menus created out of an nav element like this:

```
<nav class="nav2">      
    <li><a href="Højtalere.html">Stereo</a></li>
    <li><a href="Forstærkere.html">Højtalere</a></li>
    <li><a href="åbningstider.html">TV og hjemmebiograf</a></li>
    <li><a href="Computer.html">Streaming</a></li>
    <li><a href="Tilbehør.html">Tilbehør</a></li>
    <li><a href="Kabler.html">Kabler</a></li>       
</nav>  

<nav class="nav3">          
    <li><a href="login.html" style="display: inline;">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="support.html" style="display: inline;">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="???.html" style="display: inline;">Text</a></li>           
</nav>
```

Right now i have made the space with this css code:

```
li {
   display: inline;
   margin-right: 20px;
   }
```

The problem is that it makes the same space for all the li elements, **how do i code it so i can control lets say the nav2 should have margin-right: 10px, but the other should have 40px in space between?**

Hope you guys understand what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply:

```
li {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.nav2 li {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Oki, i didn't knew you could have two names in in the same block like .nav2 and li..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
.nav2 li {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Like this you set different rule to `li` elements that has ancestor with class `.nav2`.

Comment: Ye, like the other guy wrote.. it worked very well.. just didn't knew that!